# Create unique rows in excel with data in multiple columns

Tags: excel

I have multiple columns if data and I need to create unique rows for each LOC1 & LOC2:
Picture of mock-up:

[image]

```
LOC 1 LOC 2 FC      AMT Type
CUN   ABQ   LLA0PNR 10  AN1
CUN   AUS   BLA0PNR 15  NR2
CUN   GSP   QLA0PNR 16  AN1
CUN   DAL   HLA0PNR 14  NR2
CUN   HOU   WLA0PNR 13  AN1
CUN   ELP   RLA0PNR 12  AN3
CUN   MDW   OLA0PNR 11  NR4
```

Create:

```
CUN ABQ LLA0PNR 10  AN1
CUN ABQ BLA0PNR 15  NR2
CUN ABQ QLA0PNR 16  AN1
CUN ABQ HLA0PNR 14  NR2
CUN ABQ WLA0PNR 13  AN1
CUN ABQ RLA0PNR 12  AN3
CUN ABQ OLA0PNR 11  NR4
CUN     AUS     ......  ..      ...
CUN     AUS     ......  ..      ...
```

A row would be built for each LOC1 and LOC2 with all values in FC, AMT, Type which are constant.

Comment: The formatting of your question makes it difficult to work out what you want. Can you create a mock-up in Excel and post a screenshot into your question?

Comment: Picture of mock up: https://picasaweb.google.com/bencerob/Excelexample?authuser=0&authkey=Gv1sRgCPvPy4Gw3-y15AE&feat=directlink

Comment: Are the FC, AMT and type column fixed in E, F and G column and do they have fix number of rows of data?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you want the '[Cartesian Product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cartesian_product)' of these two tables.

**Excel Option**

Here is my sample data (shortened since I am lazy about data entry :-)

[image: Starting Data]

1. Create a 'counter' column, that increments by 1 for each row.
2. Use excel formulas to determine which row to use from table1 and table2
3. Use the excel function 'INDEX' to pull the content from each table, based on the row #s found in (2)

[image]

If you want to get fancier, you can alter the formulas to clear out after all 21 (21=7*3) entries like `=IF(Counter>(B14*C14),"",--do stuff--)`.

Here is an [example Excel workbook](https://dl.dropbox.com/u/10791482/Sample_AllCombos.xlsx), showing how it all comes together.

**SQL Option**

Though I know this is an excel question, I'd be remiss if I didn't alert you to the right tool for the job. If you can run SQL on these tables, use:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.* FROM table1 t1, table2 t2;
```

The default join for SQL is a Cartesian Product, so it all works out. This will be more elegant than convincing Excel to do it.

Answer (score 0):

Great solution, without a VB script, thanks a lot

below are the formulas used in above example:

(1) =FLOOR((A17-1)/$C$14,1)+1

(2) =MOD(A17-1,$C$14)+1

(3) =INDEX($A$3:$B$9,$B17,F$14)

(4) =INDEX($A$3:$B$9,$B17,G$14)

(5) =INDEX($D$3:$F$5,$C17,H$14)

(6)=INDEX($D$3:$F$5,$C17,I$14)

(7)=INDEX($D$3:$F$5,$C17,J$14)